# Operation on all columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, cursor, field

Is it possible to do an operation on all columns of a row in a loop?

Let's say I have a table with twenty int columns.

I want to check a condition for all columns of a row (separated) and do an operation according to condition. Can I do it with something like a loop or cursor on the columns?

Pseudo code:

```
foreach field in table1
begin
if field > 10
    print field -- (print field value)
end
```

Without the loop I have to do like this:

```
-- some select statement
if field1 > 10
    print field1
if field2 > 10
    print field2
...
if field20 > 10
    print field20
```

Comment: I recommend you to try using `CASE` statement for your issue. I believe, it can dramatically simpify your code, instead of dynamic SQL, which is quite abstract instrument and hardly grounded here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE     @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT      @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' ', '') +
            'SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TABLE_NAME, ''' +
                          COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS COLUMN_NAME, ' + 
                          COLUMN_NAME + ' AS Value FROM ' +
                          TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' > 10' +
            CASE
                WHEN c.ORDINAL_POSITION <> MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) OVER () THEN ' UNION ALL '
                ELSE ''
            END
FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE       c.TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND
            c.DATA_TYPE = 'int'
ORDER BY    c.ORDINAL_POSITION;

EXEC(@SQL);
```

This will figure which columns for the specified table (MyTable in the WHERE clause) are INT and put together to find which values in those columns are greater than 10, in this case.  Each row represents a column in the table.  The code will UNION all these rows together and execute the resulting query.  You will get something like this as output:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME Value
Table1     Col1        11
Table1     Col1        200
Table1     Col3        56
```